# ¿Como exactamente se esta evitando una inyeccion sql con pg_prepare?

Tags: php, postgresql

Si 'mysql_real_escape_string for postgresql' es usada para evitar inyecciones sql, ¿como logro reproducir el mismo el resultado con pg_prepare? ¿cual es exactamente la lógica detrás del mismo?

```
<?php

// Connect to a database named "mary"

$dbconn = pg_connect("dbname=mary");


// Prepare a query for execution

$result = pg_prepare($dbconn, "my_query", 'SELECT * FROM shops WHERE name = $1');


// Execute the prepared query.  Note that it is not necessary to escape

// the string "Joe's Widgets" in any way
 $result = pg_execute($dbconn, "my_query", array("Joe's Widgets"));


// Execute the same prepared query, this time with a different parameter


   $result = pg_execute($dbconn, "my_query", array("Clothes Clothes Clothes"));


?>
```

Fue uno de los ejemplos que vi, estoy comenzando a usar postgresql y previamente a esto solo hice dos pequeños proyectos en mysql asi que trato de adaptarme. Gracias.

Comment: el prepare crea un prepared statement en la sesión del servidor, es decir se interpreta el texto del SQL y a partir de ahí se genera un objeto/función que acepta N parámetros, luego al llamar execute se le pasa el texto/valor como parámetro (no se interpreta/evalúa como sql) asi que no podes "inyectar" nuevo sql que modifique la consulta original.

Answer (score 1):

Durante muchos años se creyó en el *mito*  de que `mysql_real_escape_string` protegía de la Inyección SQL. El tiempo ha demostrado que no, y que en ciertos escenarios se puede perpetrar perfectamente una inyección aún usando `mysql_real_escape_string`. Se puede decir que esta función no ayuda realmente a *escapar* de una inyección como se podría pensar.

La práctica ha demostrado también que la medida más robusta para proteger contra inyección SQL son las consultas preparadas.

La solidez de esta técnica es muy simple: **la consulta y los datos (elemento que un usuario mal intencionado puede manipular para inyectar código) viajan por separado**.

Por ese motivo, las consultas preparadas llevan **marcadores**, que sustituyen a los datos en sí mismos, como ocurre en tu consulta:

```
SELECT * FROM shops WHERE name = $1
```

aquí `$1` es un **marcador** que dice al sistema *ahí va un dato, luego te digo el dato que es*.

A continuación, con el método `pg_execute` le indicamos al manejador qué dato es. Si hay algo dañino será analizado y rechazado, de modo que la inyección queda neutralizada.

Aquí:

```
 $result = pg_execute($dbconn, "my_query", array("Joe's Widgets"));
```

lo que decimos al manejador es algo como: *lo prometido es deuda, este es el dato del que te hablé: `Joe's Widgets`... revisa si está todo ok y ejecuta la consulta*.

Si el manejador descubre código malicioso no ejecutará la consulta.

Este es el núcleo de lo que se conoce como consultas preparadas.

Además, las consultas preparadas tienen otra ventaja, y es que las puedes re-utilizar. La misma consulta que se preparó antes puede servir para seleccionar los registros que tengan un `name` igual a `Clothes Clothes Clothes`.

Para más detalles puedes leer la pregunta: [¿Cómo evitar la inyección SQL en PHP?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/18232/29967).  En la respuesta que he dado se explica por qué conviene el uso de consultas preparadas. Y se habla también de las configuraciones necesarias para hacer el código más robusto.

Answer (score 1):

Lectura recomendada: [The Unexpected SQL Injection](http://www.webappsec.org/projects/articles/091007.txt)

Las funciones de escape como [pg_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/es/function.pg-escape-string.php) no tienen cómo adivinar qué tipo de dato estás esperando.

Si tú pones:

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
$id_escapado=pg_escape_string($id);
$query = "SELECT * FROM tabla WHERE id=$id_escapado";
```

Perfectamente te pueden pasar por `GET` el parámetro `id=4 UNION ALL SELECT * FROM tabla`. Y esto es porque en esa cadena de texto no hay nada de malo en sí. Lo que la función no sabe es que tú esperabas un número y no un string.

Otro ejemplo: implementas un buscador para que despliegue todos los registros que **empiecen** con una cadena:

```
$cadena = $_GET['cadena'];
$cadena_escapada=pg_escape_string($cadena);
$query = "SELECT * FROM tabla where nombre LIKE '$cadena_escapada%'";
```

Perfectamente te pueden pasar por `GET` el parámetro `cadena=%hola` y modificar tu consulta para mostrar todos los registros que **contengan** la cadena. Esto porque `%hola` no tiene nada de malicioso en el contexto general, pero logró alterar el comportamiento de tu LIKE añadiéndole un comodín porque particularmente para el LIKE, el % sí tiene un significado especial.

**Conclusión: sentencias preparadas!**